# opensaml 3 signature from saml response is null

Tags: java, azure, saml, unmarshalling, opensaml

Hi i got this errormessage:

```
net.shibboleth.utilities.java.support.logic.ConstraintViolationException: Signature was null
```

On validating a SAML response from Azure AD.

For test purpose i saved a response file as xml and found a tag:

```
<ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <ds:SignedInfo>
            <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
            <ds:SignatureMethod
                Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" />
            <ds:Reference URI="#_97031c65-0139-4047-a416-9495df5d6ed7">
                <ds:Transforms>
                    <ds:Transform
                        Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
                    <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                </ds:Transforms>
                <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
                <ds:DigestValue>
                    KMaFHRt8inqVYsMGKnAryKUTQUbYGPUDPxdvj6T08OQ=
                </ds:DigestValue>
            </ds:Reference>
        </ds:SignedInfo>
        <ds:SignatureValue>
           .....
        </ds:SignatureValue>
        <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <X509Data>
                <X509Certificate>
                    ....
                </X509Certificate>
            </X509Data>
        </KeyInfo>
    </ds:Signature>
```

i unmarshall the XML response:

```
InitializationService.initialize();
DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
documentBuilderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("saml_response_azure.xml")));
Document document = docBuilder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(content.trim().getBytes()));

Element element = document.getDocumentElement();
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = XMLObjectProviderRegistrySupport.getUnmarshallerFactory().getUnmarshaller(element);
Response response = (Response) unmarshaller.unmarshall(element);
```

And error is dropped at:

```
Signature signature = response.getAssertions().get(0).getSignature() // returns null

SAMLSignatureProfileValidator profValidator = new SAMLSignatureProfileValidator();
profValidator.validate(signature);
```

Comment: Can you provide the entire response somewhere? gist for example

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Gobliins/26d8f760f120430eaeb29c223f2e436f I have replaced the credentials with some random info

Comment: Btw. in opensaml 2.6.x i didn't had this problem

Comment: I tried this https://gist.github.com/anonymous/035c2cb57780a6810909cc1b0dcdee96 and I get a signature object from your xml.

Comment: Is it the signature object that is null or do you get a nullpointer on that line? Can you check that your response object is non null?

Comment: also post you pom in a gist

Comment: I will try gist.github.com/anonymous/035c2cb57780a6810909cc1b0dcdee96 . The response and the assertion are not null, it is the signature inside the assertion.

Comment: I am still getting the nullpointer on the signature. May i see the imports from gist.github.com/anonymous/035c2cb57780a6810909cc1b0dcdee96 ?

Comment: Unfortuately i dont have a pom but i can add the libraries which i use if you want.

Comment: I have created a pom but i get different errors (see description) gist.github.com/Gobliins/a63f293001003a9cb4b61a87337c3f2e

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I think I found it, it looks like you did not add any implementation dependencies to you POM. When I use your POM and include this dependency, I get the signature object.

```
  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.opensaml</groupId>
     <artifactId>opensaml-saml-impl</artifactId>
     <version>3.2.0</version>
 </dependency>
```

The modular structure of the dependencies is a big difference from version 2 of OpenSAML.

Comment: Worked. Can you also have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41116985/opensaml-xmlns-is-not-generated-on-nameidpolicy-and-authncontext